# Open Office find all bills labelled POWER and work average cost

Tags: if-statement, sum, finance, openoffice-calc

So I have made a spreedsheet to help me keep track of my power and gas bill - well the total cost of the bill anyway. This way as the months go on I am able to see what the average Power and Gas bill have been.

I am using only sheet1 and prefer to do it this way, so when I show my partner they don't need to flick through pages of numbers. It's right in front of them with Power & Gas in the next row - take a look at the image below.

[image: Power & Gas payments and bills]

So as you can see from the above (not including the J3 row) I have everything laid out in the layout I would like. This way when I get a bill emailed to me I add it, and then I can pay X amount and record that.

I know how to do =sum() and =average() but how can I limit it to only the power rows automatically.

The query should be looking up G column for power or gas and then whichever one it is get the H column next to it and then work out the cost per month by looking at the date the bill came out.

Power bill is every month so that easy, gas is every 3 months.

I know in open office they have the =if() command and I made it return TRUE when it was power but it does not seem that i can use just that function? I am wondering if maybe a TUT or example that outlines how we get the result like this.

Another example would be replace gas and power with tech toys i.e batteries over a year what was the real cost per monthly.

Comment: to the person who downvotes and wanted to close this topic, can I ask why - Many people need to figure out functions and ways to do things when they don't use the software everyday or for that fact I have not used spreadsheets for maths or accounting EVER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after thinking outside the square - the answer I am using is this.

```
=AVERAGEIF(G3:G100;"POWER";H3:H100)/COUNTIF(G3:G100;"POWER")
```

> I divided power by it's count as we get it every month

```
=AVERAGEIF(G3:G100;"GAS";H3:H100)/COUNTIF(G3:G100;"GAS")/3
```

> I divided gas by 3 as we get it every 3rd month